# Angular FormBuilder patch value lost patched value after edit

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 7 and I came across  this strange error. I have 2 input fields in the screen where the fields expect text. User can either fill both of the fields with text or fill one and leave other one as it was (the other one can have text in it or empty). I used 'formbuilder' for this operation where my code goes like:

```
initInputsForm() {
this.inputsForm = this._fb.group({
  id: 0,
  firstInput: [null],
  secondInput: [null],
});
```

And this is the function to patch existing values to these fields:

```
loadInputs() {
this.setSpinnerStatus(true);
this.InputService.getInputsById(this.data.id).subscribe(res => {
  this.setSpinnerStatus(false);
  if (res.hasError) {
    this.toastr.error(res.message, "Error")
  }
  else {
    if (res.data != null) {
      this.inputsForm.patchValue(res.data);
    }
  }
})
```

And this is the patched value's class

```
  export class inputsModel{
  id: number;
  anotherId: number;
  firstInput: string;
  secondInput: string;
}
```

So far everything is great. But as I said the user can change these values as s/he likes. When I tried to change only one of the fields' value I kept losing the value of the other field's existing value. After trying lots of things I only changed the initial values of the form fields from 'null' to quotation mark (""):

```
initInputsForm() {
this.inputsForm = this._fb.group({
  id: 0,
  firstInput: [""],
  secondInput: [""],
});
```

when I did this I never lost the unchanged field's value. And I didn't understand why this works.

Comment: this.inputsForm .patchValue -> is this a typo for the space between inputsForm and .patchValue ?

Comment: Jacopo Sciampi yes I now noticed the typo and fixed it. That typo doesn't exist in my code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `pathValue` like this, it fails silently on nested complex errorl

```
  this.inputsForm.patchValue({
    'propertyNameOnModel1': 'ValueNeedsToBeUpdated1',
    'propertyNameOnModel2': 'ValueNeedsToBeUpdated2'
  });
    }
```

You can check [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model) for more details.